Looking for guidance on proper settings for execute-workers-max-num, prepare-workers-soft-max-num, prepare-workers-hard-max-num
Looking for some guidance on the use of --execute-workers-max-num --prepare-workers-soft-max-num --prepare-workers-hard-max-num
Say we have high core count bear metal machine and want to limit the number of cores used per node.  Are these the correct parameters to adjust?  What are the defaults and what are the optimal settings?
Thanks!
